# Turn off device when I connect another device?

Tags: windows, mouse, automation, touchpad, command-line

I want to automate the disabling of my touchpad, my display and my wifi card; when I connect my usb mouse, my 24inch lcd and my ethernet cable respectively.

Devbox does half the job by giving me a command line way to shut things down, but i don't have any way to activate it.

The most annoying on that list is that my trackpad keeps interrupting my typing and throwing me off. I can't use the touchpad drivers that come with my ASUS laptop because they are horribly buggy and make the touchpad jerky. even the updated one has that bug.

My touch pad **shows up as a ps2 mouse** to top it off.

If your answer also turns it off while typing, all the better.

Im on an Asus UL30A, with an elan touchpad.

Comment: Maybe try using the ms-dos `wmic` command, or change WMI values with VBScript or Powershell?